# In Scala, is it possible to simultaneously extend a library and have a default conversion?

Tags: scala

For example in the following article

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766

Two separate examples are given:

1. Automatic string conversion
2. Addition of append method

Suppose I want to have automatic string conversion AND a new append method.  Is this possible?  I have been trying to do both at the same time but I get compile errors.  Does that mean the two implicits are conflicting?

Comment: It is possible. Could you provide your attempt and the compilation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have any number of implicit conversions from a class *provided that* each one can be unambiguously determined depending on usage.  So the array to string and array to rich-array-class-containing-append is fine since `String` doesn't have an `append` method.  But you can't convert to `StringBuffer` which has `append` methods which would interfere with your rich array append.